# Repurposing some Javascript for a similar DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-lists

On my page I have an unordered list with some list items that serve as links to load content into a div.

The art direction requires that the list items be fully justified to the left and right. I've written some JavaScript to figure out how wide the `ul` is and calculate the width of the individual `li` elements, divide the remaining space and push the elements to the left and right respectively. It works great.

Now we want to add another `ul` under the first with another set of links.

How can I repurpose my code to do the same work as before?

All the list items are styled `display:inline;` and they need to be fluid in width in the event a font on one browser is a little bigger than another.

Here's my HTML: (It's all run together to overcome the spacing issue with inline list elements)

```
<div id="portfolio">
    <ul class="stacked-nav-top">
        <li class="project_link">
            <a href="#" class="project_class planning" id="commercial-industrial" title="Commercial Industrial Projects">
                Commercial &amp; Industrial
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="breaker">//</li>
        <li class="project_link">
            <a href="#" class="project_class planning" id="government-institutional" title="Government Institutional Projects">
                Government &amp; Institutional
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="breaker">//</li>
        <li class="project_link">
            <a href="#" class="project_class planning" id="affordable-housing" title="Affordable Housing Projects">
                Affordable Housing
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="breaker">//</li>
        <li class="project_link">
            <a href="#" class="project_class planning" id="multi-family-housing" title="Multi-family Housing Projects">
                Multi-family Housing
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$(function()
{
    var linkwidth = 0;
    $('#portfolio ul li.project_link').each(function() 
    {
        linkwidth += $(this).outerWidth()
    });

    var leftover = ($('#portfolio ul').outerWidth() - linkwidth);
    var breakerwidth = Math.floor((leftover / 3));
    $('#portfolio ul li.breaker').css('width', breakerwidth);
});
```

**EDIT**

My CSS:

```
section#portfolio ul {
    display:block;
    width:820px;
    text-align:center;
}
.stacked-nav-top {
    border-top:solid 1px rgba(97,58,17,.3);
    margin:0px;
    background:transparent url(images/dotted_line_820.png) center 19px no-repeat;
    padding:10px 0px;   
}
.stacked-nav-bottom {
    border-bottom:solid 1px rgba(97,58,17,.3);
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin:10px 0px 15px 0px;
}
section#portfolio ul li {
    display:inline;
    font:lighter .65em "Tahoma", "Geneva", sans-serif;
    color:rgb(145,145,145);
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
section#portfolio ul li.breaker {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I've tried wrapping all the JavaScript in a `$('#portfolio ul').each(...` but that doesn't seem to work. It sets the spacing according to the first `ul` not both individually.

Comment: Could you please add your CSS part ?

Comment: Added CSS. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Lee Taylor, Thank you for making my HTML readable. Anyone coming to this answer please note that I run my `li` code together in one string to avoid the inline element spacing issues talked about here: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Okay I just replaced your <div> by a <section> element to make it conform to your CSS.

Comment: @Ofeargall - I noticed that after my changes were made. I figured it'd be more useful as I had edited it. You can always roll my edit back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure to understand what do you want but,
if you want to repeat the operation on each ul of your section, you have to loop on each ul, then do your calculations.

Demo here, respecting your HTML inline syntax (inline-block problem).

http://jsfiddle.net/ggX2r/2/

```
// Inside a document.ready scope of couse...
$('#portfolio ul').each(function () {
    var linkwidth = 0,
        leftover,
        breakerwidth;

    // *this* refers to your current <ul> child of your #portfolio.
    $('li.project_link', this).each(function() {
        // *this* refers now to your current <li.project_link> element
        linkwidth += $(this).outerWidth();
    });
    leftover = ($('#portfolio ul').outerWidth() - linkwidth);
    breakerwidth = Math.floor((leftover / 3));

    $('li.breaker', this).css('width', breakerwidth);   
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. When I tried the each loop I didn't have my vars grouped together. I wonder if that's what caused it to fail for me...

Comment: Not really, it is just a good practice encouraged by JSLint !
http://www.jslint.com/

The main thing is to loop first on each <ul>, then on each <li.project_link> inside, instead of looping directly on each <li.project_link> !